# naming conventions for constants and their units

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions

Should the names of my constants incorporate the units that it represents, or is this better handled by a short comment?  Sometimes the constant names can become lengthy.  For example, I can choose between:

```
// Seconds spent displaying logo
public static final float LOGO_DISPLAY_TIMER = 1.5f;
```

and

```
public static final float LOGO_DISPLAY_TIMER_IN_SECONDS = 1.5f;
```

I've been reading [Clean code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882), which places great emphasis on accurate naming conventions, but I wasn't sure about this specific case.

Comment: Are you developing code from scratch, or adding to an existing code base? If the latter, what is the convention?

Comment: I don't know if there is any convention regarding "units" in variable names but the whole point of formatting convention is to improve code readability. If your variable names get excessively long to the point that readability is hindered, I'm not sure if the conventions are appropriate anymore, regardless of how explicitly they state a particular rule. A variable should describe its use from its name, and it seems like you're doing that just fine with the first case. Consistency is key, all else comes secondary.

Comment: @rajah9 I'm pretty much starting from scratch, but others will have to work on the codebase in the future, so I'm aiming to set up conventions for myself that will make it as readable as possible for them as well as myself.

Comment: The practice of the organization I'm in is to use the shorter name and let the next developer figure out the units. For your timer example, your comment and the scale of 1.5 is quite readable. The alternate case would be if you had said "Milliseconds" in the comment and the constant had been 1500.

Comment: If you are writing code for yourself, you should just use what you find best, but more important always use the same conventions throughout your code, it might become confusing otherwise

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion - If there are no code conventions from your company or sth. like that, take what you like and feel comfortable. The main point is that you are consistent and use every time the same style.

Answer (score 0):

Advantage of longer name is that you don't need to check the commend to know in which unit this variable is. Disadvantage is of course that it's longer :)

So as it was mentioned before - choose what you like and be consistent about it.